# multi-line ascii animation in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, printing, ascii-art

I'm trying to create a multi line ascii art animation using Intellij, and for that I'm creating an array of strings and I refer to each element of the array as a frame.
After that, in order for that to work, I need to change what was printed to the console each time unit x.

I do know that I can replace the last line printed to the console with "\r" like so:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.printf("\r %s  ", i);
    }
```

however it **doesn't delete the older lines printed** (`System.out.printf("\r %s ", "a \n b");` will only replace `b` in each iteration) and because intellij's console isn't a real console **there is no way to clear the console from code**.

So is there any other solution or a workaround for that problem that can work for intellij?

to make things more simple I'll add an example. Let's say I want to print this weight lifting animation (ascii art taken from - https://ascii.co.uk/art/stickman)

```
                                                                 O--,---,--O
                                          ._O_.     O--=-O-=--O     \ O /
    _._                      ,_O_,     O--<-+->--O      '-'          - -
   / O \        ,-O-,     O--(---)--O       X            v            -
   \| |/     O--=---=--O      >'>          / \          / )          / \
O--+=-=+--O      2"2          - -         -   -        ~  z         =   =
```

So I'm creating a 2d array of strings for the frames
(after that ill create the frame with `String.join("\n", < frame elements >)`).

```java
String[][] frames = 
{
  {
     "           ",
     "           ",
     "    _._    ",
     "   / O \\   ",
     "   \\| |/   ",
     "O--+=-=+--O"
 },
 {
     "              ",
     "              ",
     "     ,-O-,    ",
     "  O--=---=--O ",
     "      2"2     "
 },
 {
     "              ",
     "     ,_O_,    ",
     "  O--(---)--O ",
     "      >'>      ",
     "      - -      "
 },
 {
     "     ._O_.    ",
     "  O--<-+->--O ",
     "       X      ",
     "      / \\     ",
     "     -   -    "
 },
 {
     "  O--=-O-=--O ",
     "      '-'     ",
     "       v      ",
     "      / )     ",
     "     ~   Z    "
 },
 {
     "  O--,---,--O ",
     "     \\ O /    ",
     "      - -     ",
     "       -      ",
     "      / \\     ",
     "     =   =    "
 }
}
```

and in each time unit x+1 I want the console to show frames[x+1] instead of frames[x].

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, there is no way to clear the console in intellij because Intellij does not have a real console.
However you can print a lot of empty lines after every frame in order to make the old frame not visible.